# Unable to execute Snowflake PUT Command through Java

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are trying to load JSON files using Java from a file location to Snowflake Named Stage. Currently, the PUT command only works for ODBC and not JDBC. So is there any way to execute PUT command using Java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Snowflake JDBC Driver does support use of PUT statements for [local file uploads](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/v3.12.2/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeFileTransferAgent.java#L729-L737). The following java statement is considered a valid query and the file is uploaded:

```java
statement.executeQuery("PUT file:///tmp/foo.json @JSONSTAGE/ overwrite=true");
```

Running it under a logger produces logs such as the following (logs here are from JDBC driver version `v3.12.2`):

```
n.s.c.jdbc.SnowflakeFileTransferAgent$1 FINE call:778 - filePath: /tmp/foo.json
n.s.c.jdbc.SnowflakeFileTransferAgent FINE uploadFiles:1751 - Done with uploading
```

The JDBC driver also supports a more efficient way of uploading a stream directly, [documented here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-using.html#upload-data-files-directly-from-a-stream-to-an-internal-stage).