# jdbc template batch update with snowflake database is very slow

Tags: performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jdbctemplate, batch-insert

I have a spring boot application that connects to the Snowflake Database and uploads records (approx 50 columns of different data types). I am using

`JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSql, values, types)`

to do the bulk insert. Currently, it is consuming around **100** seconds for **50,000 records**. I want to improve the batch performance. but not able to find an optimal solution.

I referred to and tried the solution mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993251/jdbc-batch-insert-performance/10617768#10617768), but it didn't help at all. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you also checked in Query History in Snowflake UI to see if the insert time is related to Snowflake server side vs your app?

Comment: you cannot try the copy command route ?

Comment: @Sergiu Thanks for pointing in this direction. Snowflake is taking approx 30 seconds to insert 50k records, 70% time is used by the network + java app. I am investigating more. I will share more details regarding it

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon i can give it a try an get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved away from batch insert to [snowflake copy command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) using JDBC. It is lightning fast. With the copy command, it is barely taking 2-3 seconds to load 50000 records from a CSV file with XS (extra small) size Dataware house.

Moreover, in case of error, messages are very clear and can be viewed in **information_schema.load_history**. Different file formats can be loaded and there are a variety of options to customize load process.

In my case, I am first loading the CSV file to the internal staging area (takes less than 1 sec), Run Copy command (takes 1-2 seconds), verifying load status in information_schema.load_history table (takes a few milliseconds) and proceed accordingly

This article was also helpful for [running copy command with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68336183/how-do-i-copy-a-csv-file-into-snowflake-db-using-java)